# How to concat foreach loop with string in php

Tags: php, foreach, concatenation

How to concat the foreach loop with string in PHP like this

```
$traning [] = '<tr>
    <td style="width:30%" id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '">
    <select class="select2 form-control" data-live-search= "true" name="trainingCode[]">
        <option value="0">SELECT CODE</option>'.
        foreach ($code=0 as $row) {
            //
        }
    .'</select>
    </td>
   </tr>';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Split** code into parts that are clear to everyone:

```
$trContent = '<tr>
    <td style="width:30%" id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '">
    <select class="select2 form-control" data-live-search= "true" name="trainingCode[]">
        <option value="0">SELECT CODE</option>';

// iterate over array and append to `$trContent`
foreach ($code as $row) {
    $trContent .= '<option></option>';
}

$trContent .= '</select>
    </td>
   </tr>';

$traning [] = $trContent;
```

Comment: bro, please modify this line `'<option></option>'` i have also added my answer with few suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You have few issues in your code:

**Issue 1:** you can't concat function as like a variable, you just need to break your code and store in a variable then use Concat, otherwise, this will give you parse error.

**Issue 2:** Dont know why are you using `$code=0 as $row` in your foreach, this will give you `Invalid argument` error.

**Issue 3:** This is just my assumption, according to this `id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '"` you are using this code inside a loop, if yes then this part `name="trainingCode[]"` also will create an issue when you fetch record, how would you know the correct relation?

**Your Code Example:**

```
<?php
$myString = '<tr>
    <td style="width:30%" id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '">
    <select class="select2 form-control" data-live-search= "true" name="trainingCode[]">
        <option value="0">SELECT CODE</option>';

// use your foreach loop here
foreach ($code as $row) {
    $myString .= '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$row.'</option>'; // contact wit  $myString
}

$myString .= '</select></td></tr>';
$traning[] = $myString;
?>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no value (ever) to duplicate the option's text as a `value` attribute value.  Just use `...<option>' . implode('</option><option>', $code) . '</option>...`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$options = "";
foreach ($code=0 as $row) {
    $options .= "<option value='$code'>Code</option>";
}

$traning [] = '<tr>
<td style="width:30%" id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '">
<select class="select2 form-control" data-live-search= "true" name="trainingCode[]">
    <option value="0">SELECT CODE</option>'.
    $options
.'</select>
</td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: The hardcoded text `Code` will make it hard for users to know exactly which value they are selecting because all options will have the same visible text.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach loop inside string not the best way. But string in string.

```
$options = "";
foreach ($rows as $code) {
  $options .= '<option value="'.$code '">' . $code . '</option>';
}
$traning [] = '<tr>
    <td style="width:30%" id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '">
    <select class="select2 form-control" data-live-search= "true" name="trainingCode[]">
        <option value="0">SELECT CODE</option>'. $options .
    '</select>
    </td>
   </tr>';
```

Comment: There is absolutely no value (ever) to duplicate the option's text as a `value` attribute value.  Just use `...<option>' . implode('</option><option>', $code) . '</option>...`

Answer (score 1):

```
$htmlToConcat = "";
 foreach ($code=0 as $row) {
        $htmlToConcat .= "";
    }


$traning [] = '<tr>
    <td style="width:30%" id="trainingCode_' . $key + 1 . '">
    <select class="select2 form-control" data-live-search= "true" name="trainingCode[]">
    <option value="0">SELECT CODE</option>'.$htmlToConcat.'</select>
</td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: This code-only post does not produce any additional `<option>` tags.  Low-quality answer, rushed answer.